# upload using apache instead of nginx when nginx is enabled

Tags: apache, nginx, upload

I have nginx turned on in plesk and was wondering if it is possible to set things up to allow files to be uploaded through apache (so as if nginx was turned off)? I would like to keep all other nginx settings at default

Comment: Do you want to turn nginx off? you can tell nginx to proxy to apache certain requests.

Comment: No I don't want it off completely, I only want it disabled for the uploading of files so I can take advantage of the "php session upload progress" feature which will currently not work with nginx enabled as it bypasses apache so php cannot read the details of uploaded files. I want anyone who downloads a file from my websites to be served using nginx though. So currently for uploading, my server uses nginx, for downloading my server also uses nginx. I want for uploading my server to use apache, for downloading my server to use nginx. How can I do this?

Comment: well you can directly contact apache with it's port, but not really a method I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set apache up on a sub domain for example http://uploads.example.com and get your form to post there, once upload is done redirect to your success page.